# Replicating Stored Prcoedures

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I've been looking around on-line for an answer to this one but to no avail!

Is it possible to replicate a stored procedure which has a read-only user defined table type as a parameter?

For example:

```
CREATE TYPE [UTIL].[DATE_TIME_LIST] AS TABLE (
    [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
    [START_DATE_TIME] DATETIME,
    [END_DATE_TIME] DATETIME
)
GO

--Publisher Side
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.REPLICATION_TEST 
    (@REPLICATED_OBJECT UTIL.[DATE_TIME_LIST] READONLY)
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 
END

--Subscriber Side
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.REPLICATION_TEST 
    (@REPLICATED_OBJECT UTIL.[DATE_TIME_LIST] READONLY)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DBO.LOGGING_TABLE (ID, START_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME)
       SELECT 
           ID, START_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME 
       FROM @REPLICATED_OBJECT

    RETURN 
END
```

I would assume you'd need the custom table type on both Publisher and Subscriber databases.

Thanks.

Comment: if you replicate type as well you should have no problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you cannot replicate user-defined types, but yes the OP could have replicated any CLR User-defined-types. Hence the OP will need to create the user-defined-type explicitly on the subscribers.

Comment: So provided the type is on both sides we should be sorted? ☺

Comment: Yep all you need to do is to make sure procedure is added in the publisher articles and you are good to go,

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that... sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot replicate user-defined types unless they are CLR User-defined type.

For more details on what SQL Server objects can be or can't be replicated please see this MSDN article [`Publishing Data and Database Objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559(v=sql.105).aspx).

Hence you will need to explicitly create the user-defined type on the subscriber and then copy the stored procedure over.

**Note**

There is a setting for applying any scripts when the initial snapshot is generated, you can add this `Create type script` and let sql server manage it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replicate the user type, simply create a TSQL script with the code, and then set the @pre_snapshot_script variable appropriately in sp_addpublication.  When you run and apply your snapshot, the script will automatically be executed on the subscriber.  Of course if you alter the datatype at the publisher, you'll need to manually alter the script, and manually alter the type on the subscriber if you don't want to reinit.